# Angular: need to get some settings from server for a module prior to its components run. Where to place the logic?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a sub-system module and it requires some configuration from server. 
So I can put the logic to APP_INITIALIZER but then it will be executed even if user will never ever run something from the module.

Another option is to put the module initialization logic to app-routing module and run it once if certain path is being visited. But in this case I don't know how to get the injector to perform the call:

```
const routes: Routes = 
[{ path: 'myPath', loadChildren: async ()=>{
  await configureIfNotConfigured();
  return import('src/app/myFolder/myModule').then(m=>m.MyModule);
}}]

configured=false;
function configureIfNotConfigured(): Promise<any>{
if(!configured){
    // Do a call to server then configured=true; 
  }
}
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Is it possible to pass the root injector to configureIfNotConfigured somehow?

Are there there any other options for module initialization?

Thanks!

Comment: You can google for "Angular Route Resolvers". The purpose of a resolver is to obtain some data before navigating to the route. Take a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-route-resolvers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey whats about a Guard? If there is no configuration, the Guard can get it.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow missed the option